# AsyncTask FATAL ERROR #3

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fatal-error

Here is my doInbackground method for async task extended method i got fatal error #4 here.. its my code for calling a web service through the asynctask extended method

```
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        String MESSAGE=null;
        String NUMBER=null;
         String pass=settings.getString("username","").toString();
    String nam=settings.getString("sender","").toString();
    String uri=settings.getString("type", "").toString();

       try
        {
         MESSAGE= URLEncoder.encode(params[0],"UTF-8");
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            NUMBER=URLEncoder.encode(params[1],"UTF-8");
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }



        if(uri.equals("LM1"))
        {
            uri="http://userd.gjsms.net/api/v1/sms/single.json?token="+pass+"&sender_id="+nam+"&msisdn="+NUMBER+"&text="+MESSAGE+"&route=TRANS";
        }
        MyHandler mine=new MyHandler();
        String json=mine.makeServiceCall(uri);
        if(json!=null)
        {
            try{
                JSONObject job=new JSONObject(json);
                boolean error=job.getBoolean("error");
                if(error)
                {
                    Log.e("Add Prediction Error: ",
                            "> " + job.getString("message"));
                }
            }catch (JSONException e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        else
        {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "JSON data error!");
        }


        return null;
    }
```

my Error list displayed here

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
Process: com.example.web03.bulkmessenger, PID: 32230
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()                                                                            
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)                                                                            
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)                                                                                                                                                      
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)                                                                                        
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)                                                                               
 at                                                                                 

                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=LM2
                                                                                at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:2588)
                                                                                at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1250)
                                                                                at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:707)
                                                                                at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:699)
                                                                                at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:520)
                                                                                at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:498)
                                                                                at handler.MyHandler.makeServiceCall(MyHandler.java:45)
                                                                                at handler.MyHandler.makeServiceCall(MyHandler.java:33)
                                                                                at com.example.web03.bulkmessenger.MessageActivity$AsynctaskRunner.doInBackground(MessageActivity.java:124)
                                                                                at com.example.web03.bulkmessenger.MessageActivity$AsynctaskRunner.doInBackground(MessageActivity.java:83)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

hope you will understand my  rpoblem
thanks for help in advance...

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Why did you return null when the method expect return a String?

Comment: @HendraWijayaDjiono: can u please update  my code ?

Comment: i mean you can use something like AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> instead of AsyncTask<String, Void, String>

Comment: Anyway pleas check the web that you trying to reach, is it active? Do you have internet connection in your device? Have you put <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET/> in your manifest? Did you put correct parameters to your HTTP request? The problem is because of HTTP connection

Comment: @HendraWijayaDjiono thanks itz works

Answer (score 1):

It's the case when you don't have the uri. You are checking condition and assigning value to URI but if the condition fails, your uri is null and hence the error.